# Can JavaScript be used in a mobile web page to count items?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, arrays

What I need to do is the following, and I'm not sure what the best way to approach it is. I need to create a mobile web page that counts things... there will be four specific things that need to be counted in a particular session. What I would like the user to be able to do is this:

- Click a button to start the counting session
- Click a button representing one of the four things to be counted (chicken, cow, dog, cat, for example)
- Increment the count in what I would assume would be a javacript array or something
- Click a button to end the counting session
- Total the number of each item
- Write the results to a mySQL database

So, that's pretty much it. I'm not sure what's the best technology to use to do this dynamic counting from a single web page... it would have to continue to update a local array or something, and then write the final results to a database.

Can this be done in JavaScript, and if so, could somebody point me to an example of how I might be able to implement it? Or, is there a better way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off using jQuery because its so awesome and you can do so much by writing so less .

I'm assuming the following

- a button to start counting , ID = `startcount`
- 4 other buttons , ID = `chicken` , `cow` , `dog` , `cat` with class = `clickme`
- a button to stop counting , ID = `stopcount`
- a flag , ID = `countstarted` to keep track

Since here you're talking about only 4 other buttons (chicken , cow .. ) i would make 4 variables for them to store their respective count .

So i think the code , is this:

```
var countstarted,chicken_count,cow_count,dog_count,cat_count;
countstarted = 0;

$('#startcount').click(function(){
countstarted = 1;
});

$('.clickme').click(function(){
if (!countstarted)
 return;

var clicked = $(this).attr('id');

if (clicked == 'chicken')
    chicken_count++;
//all other cases here

});

$('#stopcount').click(function(){
countstarted = 0;

// construct a JSON out of those (ask me if you dont know how to) and send it to the backend.

});
```

Hope i understood your question . Hope this helps.

Peace.

Comment: That looks like a viable solution! Thanks! I'll give it a shot soon and see how it turns out...I may be back for more help.

Peace!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by counting items. What Items ? Where are they ? But regardless of your case: If it is possible to do on desktop browsers, Potentially you can do the same thing on mobile browsers, but not all mobile browsers support that ! [This link](http://quirksmode.org/m/table.html) covers most of major phone browsers. It's not a 100% complete resource, but you can get some ideas.

Comment: Let's pretend that I'm at a farm, and I'm counting types of animals going through a chute. For each type that comes by, I would hit a button and increment the count. That's what I'm talking about. A generic example that could be expanded to counting many other things.